# Does vncviewer require X locally?

Tags: xorg, vncviewer

Does vncviewer require an X server to work?

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, as well as the xtightvncviewer package.  When running vncviewer, it claims that it cannot find the display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need X server. Won't work from Linux server with no X server.

Assuming you have an X server, you can run

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

unless your display manager is not running on the default X display.